# Is there a way to set adapter position of view holder of recycler view programmatically?

Tags: java, android

Just like a view holder has the method getAdapterPosition(), I want to write my own setAdapterPosition() for the view holder(which doesn't exist).

**What am I working on?**

Currently, I am working on a project wherein I have to list 10 songs in the form of a recycler view and then play them, if any particular song is clicked. Each list item contains the song name, a seek bar and a play button

I have implemented this part, by adding all the media player contros inside the adapter class.

**What do I want?**

Currently, this model used mediaPlayer.setLooping(true) so that as soon as a song finished, it kept looping till some other song is clicked for playing.

Now I want to extend this model to an "autoplay" version so that as soon as a song is finished, the next song is played

**What is the problem?**

The seekBar progress and playButton image transition to a pauseButton image were happening with the call

```
viewHolder.seekBar.setProgress(...)

viewHolder.playButton.setImageDrawable(...)
```

Since this was happening on the

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(...)
```

as soon as a new song was clicked, the seekBar and playButton image were being updated.

Now, when the song is completed, I don't want the user to click on the next song to play it. I want it to be autoplayed, but I am unable to understand, how do I change myViewHolder position accordingly.

Suppose Song 0 has finished playing and Song 1 has started playing, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() still returns 0 instead of 1. Hence the seekBar & playButton of song 0 is being updated and not of song 1.

I want to be able to do something like this

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        int nextSongPosition, currentSongPosition;
                        currentSongPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                        if(currentSongPosition==(songs.size()-1)){
                            nextSongPosition = 0;
                            //do some miracle so that viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() now shows 0 instead of currentSongPosition
                        }else{
                            nextSongPosition = currentSongPosition + 1;
                            //do some miracle so that viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() now shows nextSongPosition instead of the currentSongPosition;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

As clear from the question statement, I want to implement something similar to a setAdapterPosition() which doesn't exist.

**EDIT 1**

**onBindViewHolder Code:**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Song song = songs.get(i);
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                audioManager = (AudioManager) Objects.requireNonNull(context).getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    pauseMediaPlayer(viewHolder);
                }else{
                    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Songs");
                    StorageReference dateRef = storageRef.child(song.getStoredAs());
                    dateRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            try {
                                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri.toString());
                                mediaPlayer.prepare();

                                viewHolder.seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
                                mSeekbarUpdateHandler = new Handler();
                                mUpdateSeekbar = new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (viewHolder.seekBar != null && mediaPlayer != null) {
                                            try{
                                                viewHolder.seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000);
                                                mSeekbarUpdateHandler.postDelayed(this, 50);
                                            } catch(IllegalStateException e){
                                                Log.i("Exception",e.toString());
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                };


                                viewHolder.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                                        if (fromUser && mediaPlayer != null)
                                            mediaPlayer.seekTo( progress * 1000);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                                    }
                                });

                                startMediaPlayer(viewHolder);

                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Handle any errors
                            Log.i("Song Loading Error",  exception.toString());
                        }
                    });
                }

            }


        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                int nextSongPosition, currentSongPosition;
                currentSongPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                if(currentSongPosition==(songs.size()-1)){
                    nextSongPosition = 0;
                    //do some miracle so that viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() now shows 0 instead of currentSongPosition
                }else{
                    nextSongPosition = currentSongPosition + 1;
                    //do some miracle so that viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() now shows nextSongPosition instead of the currentSongPosition;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**pauseMediaPlayer(..) & startMediaPlayer(..) Code:**

```
private void pauseMediaPlayer(ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            isSongPlaying = false;
            viewHolder.playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button);
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startMediaPlayer(ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            isSongPlaying = true;
            viewHolder.playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_button);
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                //mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            mSeekbarUpdateHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateSeekbar, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where you setOnCompletionListener? inside Holder?. I think your problem is OnCompletionListener keep not correct viewHolder so it returns adapter position not correctly

Comment: I have set it inside the onBindViewHolder(...)

Comment: Could you attach code of your holder?

Comment: Share the code for onBindViewHolder.

Comment: I've made the edits, kindly check them